# bootstrap container - containing divs with over 100% width because of absolute positioning

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, css-position

I'm putting divs with 100% inside a bootstrap container. Some of the divs have additional elements that are positioned with absolute-positioning to go outside of the container:

```
.inst-link {
    color:#414447db;
    background-color: transparent;
    font-size: 3rem;
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
    border: 1px solid #ECEFEF;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px #d1d1d1;
    transition: box-shadow 100ms ease-in-out;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 15px 20px;
    outline: none;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    position: relative;
}
.inst-link::before {
    font-family:"Font Awesome 5 Free";
      content: '\f359';
      color: #2ecc71;
      position: absolute;
      right: 0;
      margin-right: -50px;
}
```

Relavant html for the matter:

```
<div class"container">
    <div class="inst-link"></div>
</div>
```

As you can see the div inst-link has adjacant elements with absolute positioning that the container div cannot take into account.

The result is that on most screen widths it looks fine but before each breaking point the absolute positioned elements go outside of the screen. In other words, right before a breaking point, when the divs become smaller, the absolute positioned elements go outside of the screen. I'm guessing an option would be to change the breaking points?

[image]

[image]

What could be a good way to fix the issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The container represent the largest width for your content. If you had content outside of the wrapper on low width device (tablet or mobile). The content overflow the viewport.
You can hide it with a media query

```
@media (min-width: 960px) {
    .inst-link::before {
        font-family:"Font Awesome 5 Free";
        content: '\f359';
        color: #2ecc71;
        position: absolute;
        right: 0;
        margin-right: -50px;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but the problem is not about hiding it. After each breaking point it looks fine, but a bit before the breaking point (which makes the divs smaller), the elements go outside of the container.
I'll edit the question to stress it

Comment: If you can setup a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/) it could help a lot ?

Comment: Thanks Laurent I guess I should delete this question and post a new one with jsfiddle link